# include в django

Tags: python, django

пытаюсь в файле urls.py выполнить

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
app_name = 'mywebchild'
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('hello/', include('firstpage.urls', 'firstpage'), namespace = 'firstpage'),
]
```

Выдает ошибку 'Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name '
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.
Что делать?

Answer (score 1):

`namespace` - это параметр функции [`include`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/#include).

Замените на:

```py
...
urlpatterns = [
    path('hello/', include('firstpage.urls', namespace='firstpage')),
    ...
]
```